# How can I modify the length of a div based on the length of the string within it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to dynamically stretch my `div`s based on the length of the string within it. How can this be done?

```
<div width=magic_function();>
     pickle
</div>
```

I'm currently using php's `strlen` in a clever way to achieve this, but I feel it is process-intense.

```
<style>
    .tag {
        padding-bottom:2px;
        position:relative;
        background:#BFC9D9;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;
        width:???;
        text-align:center;
        border-top-right-radius:2px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:2px;
        margin-top:3px;
        margin-bottom:3px;
    }
    .tag:after {
        right:100%;
        top:50%;
        border:solid transparent;
        content: " ";
        height:0;
        width:0;
        position:absolute;
        border-right-color:#BFC9D9;
        border-width:10px;
        margin-top:-10px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: your div should be resized based on the text in it by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  .tag {
         display:inline;
         width:auto;
        }
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. Probably should check my update.

Comment: Your second update in addition to my code made the div flush left.

Comment: use display:table to center it if you want